# Is it possible to have a property in the properties windows with a list of inherited classes?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a custom control, extending `TextBox`. In it, a property of type `SomeAbstractClass` is exposed. I want to be able to set the actual instantiable inherited class via the properties window.

So for example, if these are the classes:

```
abstract class SomeAbstractClass
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
class InstantiableClass1 : SomeAbstractClass
{
    InstantiableClass1(int number)
    {
        SomeProperty = number;
    }
}
class InstantiableClass2 : SomeAbstractClass
{
    public string AnotherProperty;

    InstantiableClass2(int number, string text)
    {
        SomeProperty = number;
        AnotherProperty = text;
    }
}
```

and this is the custom control:

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SomeAbstractClass SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

then when selecting the `CustomTextBox`, under the `SomeProperty` property in the Properties window, I could choose between `InstantiableClass1` and `InstantiableClass2`.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could have a surrogate property with an enum type which sets the real property in its setter.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thanks! What if I need to pass a parameter to the class constructor? I have edited the question to demonstrate. Thanks!

Comment: So, how are you expecting this to work in the property editor? Do you need to specify the value of the parameter at design time?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Yes.

Comment: OK.. So, I guess you could add *another* surrogate for that int value, and reinstantiate `SomeProperty` in the setters of both surrogates.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thanks! Could you please elaborate in an answer with an example?

Comment: Well, ok. I wrote out an example - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example (untested, but you get the idea) of using surrogate properties for this purpose.

```
enum SomeClassType {
    None,
    InstantiableClass1,
    InstantiableClass2
}

class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    private int _number = 0;
    private SomeClassType _someClassType = SomeClassType.None;

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public SomeAbstractClass SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Number { 
        get { return _number; }
        set { _number = value; CreateSomeClass(); }
    }

    [DefaultValue(SomeClassType.None)]
    public SomeClassType SomeClassType {
        get { return _someClassType; }
        set { _someClassType = value; CreateSomeClass(); }
    }

    private void CreateSomeClass() {
        switch (_someClassType) {
            case SomeClassType.InstantiableClass1:
                SomeProperty = new InstantiableClass1(_number);
                break;
            case SomeClassType.InstantiableClass2:
                SomeProperty = new InstantiableClass2(_number);
                break;
            default:
                SomeProperty = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! After testing this solution, I understood that I misexplained my question. It is not guaranteed that the instantiable classes' constructors have the same signature, and therefore, having a `Number` property in the custom `TextBox` itself is not a solution. I want to be able to set the properties **based** on which class has been chosen. What I have in mind is a bit similar to the VS collection editor: when you add an item to the list, you can set its properties. I have edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you again!

Comment: Please notice my previous question and the changes I have made to the question. Thanks again!